# PHP MVC Globals Variables

Tags: php, variables, global

I have a little doubt, I understand that using global variables is a bad practice.

I have a small MVC application with php, in which I would like to create a file .. called config.php and inside it, save the global variables that I will use in my classes, example ...

```
$config = array ();
$config ['db_host'] = 'localhost';
```

Now, I would like to know what would be the recommended way to include this file in my application .. I have implemented a autoloader, I could include it in this ...

```
Class Autoload
{
    public function __construct () {
        global $ config;
        require_once 'config.php';
    }
}
```

But I really do not know if this is a good practice ...

Thank you very much in advance..

Comment: That is not a good practice

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. Could you help me find a better way to do it? I really can not think of another one. Many thanks again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking it's not a good practice to use globals or singletons.  What you want instead is called "dependency injection."  This pattern enables you to use mock objects for testing.  Some of the philosophy and practice of dependency injection is available in this article.
https://iconoun.com/blog/2017/05/05/php-globals-vs-dependencies/

Comment: Wow! .. excellent article, I am reading, when finished reading it, surely you take my best answer .. Many, many thanks for this excellent article

Answer (score 0):

Instead of globals you could create a `class`, like this

```
class Autoload {

    public $value1;
    public $value2;
    public static instances = array();

    public static function instantiate($className) {
        if (isset($instances[$className])) {
            return $instances[$className];
        }
        $newInstance = new $className();
        $newInstance->value1 = "foo";
        $newInstance->value2 = "bar";
        return $instances[$className] = $newInstance;
    }
}
```

And you can inherit this `class` for more specific cases, for instance, different user types.